# How to get a tensor product symbol

Tags: symbols, tensor

Im trying to insert a tensor product symbol (a circle with a cross through it) into my document. Anyone know how i might achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: `\otimes` ou `bigotimes`.

Comment: What editor are you using? Almost of them has a panel with common symbols.

Comment: Have a look on this too:  http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilfe:TeX  it is german, but I think, the symbols should speak for themself.;)

Comment: @user3771983: See http://write-math.com/view/?raw_data_id=12765 - you can write the symbol there and include the link on tex.stackexchange so that people see what you mean.